# Finding if a string is a repeated substring in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

Here is the problem:
A string is called a k-string if it can be represented as k concatenated copies of some string. For example, the string "aabaabaabaab" is at the same time a 1-string, a 2-string and a 4-string, but it is not a 3-string, a 5-string, or a 6-string and so on. Obviously any string is a 1-string.

You are given a string s, consisting of lowercase English letters and a positive integer k. Your task is to reorder the letters in the string s in such a way that the resulting string is a k-string.

Input
The first input line contains integer k (1 ≤ k ≤ 1000). The second line contains s, all characters in s are lowercase English letters. The string length s satisfies the inequality 1 ≤ |s| ≤ 1000, where |s| is the length of string s.

Output
Rearrange the letters in string s in such a way that the result is a k-string. Print the result on a single output line. If there are multiple solutions, print any of them.

If the solution doesn't exist, print "-1" (without quotes).

Here is my code:

```
k = gets.to_i
str = gets.chomp.split(//)
n = str.length/k
map = Hash.new(0)
map2 = Hash.new(0)
str.each { |i| map[i] += 1 }

x = str.uniq.permutation(n).map(&:join).each do |string|
  string.each_char { |c| map2[c] += k }
  if map2 == map
    puts string*k
    exit
  end
  map2 = Hash.new(0)
end

puts '-1'
```

To me this solution seems like it should work, but it fails on a test case.  Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: On what test case does it fail and how does it fail?

Comment: It would help if you showed us the test cases as well.

Comment: This seems terribly brute force. If I understand the definition of a k-string, each character must occur a multiple of k times. Thus I would probably sort the characters, count their occurrence, and see if each satisfies that criterion. If not, then print -1. Otherwise find the subset of characters that represent one "unit", order them in a random manner, and repeat k times.

Comment: @Floris I don't understand.  If a k-string means what you say, then for k=2 aaaazzaaaabb would not be a k-string.  But in actuality it is, because it can be turned into the string aaaazbaaaazb

Comment: @Floris Never mind, I see that you said a *multiple* of k.  So that means {character count}%k must = 0

Comment: Isn't the order of the letters in the original string insignificant? All that matters is how many times each letter appears.

Comment: @ordinary one thing could you say that? - if in that case main string and sub-string is known to you? With that substring you would like to test if it presents in the main string more than once or not- right?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution.

Just create one segment, then output it `k` times. If a character does not appear k times (or a multiple of it), then stop early and output -1.

```
k = gets.to_i
str = gets.chomp.split(//)
counts = Hash.new(0)
str.each { |i| counts[i] += 1 }

out = ''
str.uniq.each do |c|
  if counts[c] % k != 0
    puts -1
    exit
  end
  out = out + c*(counts[c]/k)
end

puts out*k
```